# active class being applied to all anchor elements instead of just the clicked one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Services</div>
      {{#each}}
        <div class="list-group">
          {{#link-to 'service' this class="list-group-item"}}
            <span class="badge">6</span>
            {{dateCreated}}
            <small class="text-muted">by {{createdBy}}</small>
          {{/link-to}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{#link-to 'service' class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right"}}New Service{{/link-to}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">{{outlet}}</div>
</div>
```

When one of the `list-group-item` anchors is clicked, the `.active` class is being added to all the anchor tags rather than only the one I clicked.  I'm not sure why or how to solve it.

Comment: just a guess but you might need to wrap the list-group-item in a <ul></ul>

Comment: Could you put together a jsBin (emberjs.jsbin.com)?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I created one and it works as expected.  So now I'm going through my code and trying to see what is different, even though it was all just copy and paste.